# how to add a maven dependency when customizing udf functions

Tags: hive, user-defined-functions, hdp

In the hadoop HDP platform, how to add a maven dependency when customizing udf functions,what should be paid attention to

Answer (score 0):

Start with basic dependencies, e.g.,

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-client</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.0</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hive</groupId>
      <artifactId>hive-exec</artifactId>
      <version>2.3.7</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```